# Upgrade Linux Kernel to 2.6.39.1?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

Can i upgrade my linux Kernel 2.6.38 to the new one 2.6.39.1? Is it safe and stable to upgrade it in my Ubuntu Natty?

THNX!

Comment: Next question: [Problems to boot on Natty with Kernel 2.6.39.1](http://askubuntu.com/q/47842/6969)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Kernel PPA**

The Ubuntu Kernel team [have a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=natty) which they maintain with the latest version of the kernel for Natty - having just checked, the current version in the repo is 2.6.39-0.5

**Mainline Builds**

If you want to test more vanilla Kernel Builds then the kernel team also do nightly builds as well as builds for each release candidate.

For example - the new v3 kernel builds are [available](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) - these are tagged as -oneric.  Obviously these builds are specifically been built for the next version of ubuntu in mind.  Also, if you install them, you'll need to keep up-to-date yourself.

**Change info for Kernel 2.6.39**

However - there is little point in upgrading a kernel unless you are having serious issues with you current official Natty kernel.  What do you expect to gain?

Is it "safe and stable" - arguable terms.  Linus T calls it stable.  There are many thousands of users using 2.6.38 in Natty and many of the latest distros.

Linus produces a [change-log](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/ChangeLog-2.6.39) for each kernel release.  In my mind, this is a bit deep for me.  There are a few sites, such as [this](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/What-s-new-in-Linux-2-6-39-1242910.html), that explains what new changes are available a bit more clearly.

Comment: I've read that the newest version was out and it was stable. I wanted to see what was the diference between the old and this one. Thnx.

Comment: @jorge-pinho - ok, have updated.

Comment: Thnx for your answer fossfreedom :D

Comment: Ok. I've read that there is some issues on AMD Graphics... And they will fix it sooner. So, i'll have to wait for... Thnx friend!

Comment: @jorge-pinho - you are most welcome.  If the question is closed, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @jorge-pinho - added more info for v3 if you wish to try this.

Comment: Thnx, I've seen it already. Let's give it a try. I will post something here (new post) if have any doubts... Hope everything goes right :D

Answer (score 2):

i advise to get it one step forward and install kernel 3.0.0 (also known as 2.6.40 but officially it's 3.0)
It's release candidate and  so far working perfectly for me (fixing described above bug with radeon)

Comment: Can you put here the links to do it? Please? :D

Answer (score 1):

I installed it.

NOT stable, had serious issues with my ATI card, ran occasionally with Unity but usually just failed to load the GUI, ran OK in Failsafe mode - but what fun is that?

I'm anything but an expert but I had a lot of difficulty getting back to the previous kernel.

Obviosly works for some, but unless you are prepared for fun and games ....