# Problems to boot on Natty with Kernel 2.6.39.1

Tags: kernel, 64-bit

I've installed this new Kernel version (2.6.39.1) and it seems to me that isn't stable. When i boot my laptop it blocks.... and it shows a Fail on Graphics... What is the problem?

I've installed proprietary drivers FGLRX.

My Laptop is a Acer Aspire 5542G
AMD64 bits
ATI Radeon HD4570
4gb Memory

I'll wait for an answer, please...

Here it is my proprietary graphics:

[image]

This installation problem shows me this:

[image]

Comment: please confirm the exact error message displayed when booting - when do you see it.  Also confirm in your question, what happens if you remove the driver, remove /etc/X11/xorg.conf.  Does the laptop boot correctly?

Comment: No. It doesn't boot well. It blocks at certain time and appears that everything boots ok. At a moment it blocks and shows that the graphics boot "Fail"...

Comment: This sounds like a bug report...

Comment: yes, indeed. I've already sent my bug report...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very similar Question was recently raised [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50687/fglrx-catalyst-11-6-is-it-compatible-with-kernel-2-6-39/50688#50688).

The resolve the black screens for the proprietary FGLRX catalyst driver, you will need to patch the kernel.

Therefore, boot with your natty kernel and remove the FGLRX catalyst driver. You should be able to boot with the open-source driver.  Reboot into the new kernel.

In the linked question try either of the two solutions depending upon whether you are using Catalyst v11.5 or Catalyst v11.6.

Comment: Kernel 2.6.39-2 solves the compatibility for FGLRX